# Fix the problem "unable to determine the relationship..." Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm tried to create a database but got a problem

> Unable to determine the relationship presented by navigation 'Movie.Actors' of  type 'HashSet< Person>'

What is wrong with my code?

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Person> Actors { get; set; }
    public Person Director { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public Movie() { }

    public Movie(string id, string name, double rating, HashSet<Person> actors, Person director, HashSet<Tag> tags)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Rating = rating;
        Actors = actors;
        Director = director;
        Tags = tags;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Movie> ActorMovies { get; set; }

    public Person() { }

    public Person(string id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

class ApplicationContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Movies;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
 }
```

Is is something about 'many-to-many' relationships? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: *Is is something about 'many-to-many' relationships?* - it's actually something to do with many relationships ;)

Answer (score 0):

EF is struggling because you've connected Movie to Person twice, once Movie-has-many-Actor-Persons and once via Movie-has-one-Person-Director. To you it's obvious which way round it is, but EF may reasonably see:

- a many:many from Movie.Actors:Person.Movies or
- a one:many from Movie.Director:Person.Movies

and it won't be able to decide. As such you'll have to tell it so it can understand the map. It would perhaps look like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().HasMany(m => m.Actors).WithMany(p => p.ActorMovies);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().HasOne(m => m.Director);
}
```

There isn't a property that maps a Person to the directorships they have, but if you did add some `public ICollection<Movie> DirectedMovies { get; set; }  = new HashSet<Movie>();` to Person, then you'd specify that as `.HasOne(m => m.Director).WithMany(p => p.DirectedMovies)`

FWIW, you might want to rename `ActorMovies` to `ActedInMovies`..

<sub>Side note: EF5+ is needed for many-many support</sub>

---

All that said, movies in the real world can have more than one director. In my mind I think I'd model things like:

```
class Person{
  ICollection<MoviePerson> Movies {get;set;}
}

class Movie{
  ICollection<MoviePerson> People {get;set;}
}

class MoviePerson{
  Movie Movie {get;set;}
  Person Person {get;set;}
  Role Role {get;set;}
}

enum Role{
  Actor,
  Director
}
```

It allows any number of any types of Person with some Role to be associated with a Movie, and EF will be able to figure it out without needing any mapping instruction